# Rigidbody not updating, and not deleting bake

Tags: physics, rigidbody

I have 2 objects both with rigid body. One object is active, the other is passive. One active object should be moving after I hit the playback (as its done in the past). However, now the object is not reacting to anything. I've tried deleting the bake within scene properties, however that does nothing as well.

I've tried:
deleting the bake
turning on and off gravity (i've read this resets the rigidbody system).
changing all my objects from convex/mesh.
removing/adding rigidbody systems to the objects

I've been working on this, trying many different little things for 3 days, and am at a lost now :(

Comment: maybe you've enabled the Rigid Body "Animated" option? If it's not the case, could you share your file (only keep the object): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Animated option is turned off.

Here is a blend with only the 2 models with the broken rigid bodys. I have also tried using rigid body constraints, but no luck there either as the whole rigid body system seems to be messed up somehow

https://pasteall.org/blend/52cfec70673f44809cd8bf320ffab28f

Comment: if you append in a new file it will works but it doesn't answer

Comment: it looks like if you Delete All Bakes then Bake All Dynamics it works, I don't know why though

Comment: It only worked for me one time, in my scene with the rest of the character. Almost every time bake all dynamics did nothing either. That's ok though. I was going to use rigid bodies to make googly eyes, but its too much of a pain, so I've decided to stick with a traditional eye system, and not use googly eyes!

Comment: Have you first Delete All Bakes? Also as I said you can try to append to a new file. Anyway yes perhaps it's not the best solution for eyes

Comment: Yes, i've tried deleting the bake many times

Comment: Blender 3.6 same issue still exists. After baking rigidbody it gets stuck, I have to delete the rigibody from physics, and assign a new one, this is time consuming when working with cell fracture and over 300 RB. And appears to be the only way to recover the project.